# How can I see the React Native output on the windows?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I started to learn React Native, I read the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/)

But I have a question about simulate the React Native apps on the windows ...

According to the docs, I installed expo.io on my iPhone and I saw the built app without any problem, and this is possible on android devices too with expo and a wireless connection !

But trace and check is very difficult with this method !

I searched about this issue and I did not find a good article about this problem.

I just found some articles about the native mobile programming with java and swift or proprietary simulators ...

I use windows 7 and I have not MacBook or MacOS. Apparently it is possible with "npm run ios" or "npm run android" just on the Mac systems only.

But, how can I simulate the react native apps on the windows ?!

Thank you

Comment: The Android-SDK comes with an emulator for Windows.

Comment: @ChrisG i see , but i am not android developer, i am front-end developer and i work with ReactJS + Redux. i am interested in learning mobile development with react native and i think android sdk is not right solution for this issue ....

Comment: React-Native can publish your app for either Android or iOS. You already have the iOS part down with your iPhone. If you want to test-run your app without your phone, on a Windows machine, you *have* to use an Android emulator. You can pay for Genymotion's, or use the free one that's available from the Android SDK. Your choice.

Comment: The answer to `How can I see the React Native output on the windows?` is: "install an Android emulator". Period. (and since having react-native push to android requires the SDK, you might as well use the free emulator it already contains).